# instantiation of variables in body of lambda

Tags: java, lambda, local-variables

I write all the rules of lambda expression, but I have a doubt about it.

**When to use lambda**

A lamda expression is used only to override an abstract method of a functional interface. Not to override methods of concrete classes, abstract classes or not functional interfaces. Infact in all these cases there will be a compiler error.

**Body of lambda: relationship between return and {}**

- If I put the body of lambda  in braces {} and the abstract method of my functional interface returns a type, I have to use return + ;
- If I put the body of lambda in braces{} and the abstract method of my functional interface returns void, I don't have to use return + ;
- If I don't put the body of lambda in braces {}, I can't use return + ;

Infact, I have:

```
interface MiaInterfaccia{
    int assignment();
}

public class TestAssignmentOperator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MiaInterfaccia m = () -> { int c = 0; }; //compilation error because, compiler adds 'the return;' so the return is void and not int

        int c = 5;
        MiaInterfaccia m = () -> c; //it is ok
   }
}
```

The braces {} are mandatory if:

- I have more than a statement;
- I need to return (explicitly or implicitly).

**Parameters of lambda**

- The parameters of my lambda expression must have different name from the local variables of the method or block where my lambda is in.
- If I have 0 parameter or more than one parameter, the brackets () are mandatory.
- If I have only one parameter the brackets () aren't mandatory
- It isn't mandatory to declare the type of the parameters, if it is explicity.

**Body of lambda: variables and 'this'**

In the body of my lambda expression I can take

- local variables, if they are final or effectively final;
- instance variables, it isn't necessary they are final;
- static variables, it isn't necessary they are final;

In the body of my lambda expression, I can :

- declare 'this' if the lambda is in a instance method;
- declare 'this' if the lambda is an instance variable.

If the lambda is in a static method I can't declare 'this' in the body of my lambda expression, otherwise there will be a compilation error.

This is my question: I know that in the body of my lambda expression, I can declare variables and they can be final or not. But in my code I have compiler error:

```
interface MiaInterfaccia{
    int assignment();
}

public class TestAssignmentOperator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MiaInterfaccia m = () -> int c = 0; //compilation error
    }
}
```

Why is there this compiler error?

Thanks a lot!

A.

Comment: Variable declaration is not an expression and it doesn't return a value. It's not just about lambda expression. You also cannot write for example `if (boolean a = true) {//do something}` - that's also illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there this compiler error?

Because the Java language designers decided, rightfully, that the syntax you're proposing adds no value. We already know the return type; we can see it from `MiaInterfaccia`. It's an `int`.

What use is the identifier `c` providing? It's not available in any scope, so nothing can ever possibly refer to it.

Lambdas were added to *reduce* the verbosity of anonymous inner classes. `int c =` is only adding unnecessary verbosity.

The correct way to write it is

```
MiaInterfaccia m = () -> 0;
```

If you prefer to think of it as the compiler adding implicit returns (I don't personally find that helpful, but you seem to find it compelling) then the following isn't valid Java either.

```
int foo()
{
    return int c = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your lambda `() -> int c = 0;` has void type. 
If you wan't to use return that local variable that just replace it with

```
 MiaInterfaccia m = () -> {
     int c = 0; 
     return c;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Naya mentioned, i just want add that is if you don't want to use braces then
it only possible statement is one and that must be return value,

But here,

```
int c = 0;
```

is not returning anything,
If you want try out with boolean you will get better idea about how value will be returned when you have single statement,

```
Boolean assignment();

MiaInterfaccia m = () ->  true == false;
MiaInterfaccia m = () ->  true;
MiaInterfaccia m = () ->  false;
MiaInterfaccia m = () ->  true != false;
```